# Convert random numbers with a specific range in a date

Tags: java, date, random

I'm trying to read in random numbers and convert them into a date. I tried doing it for a first number using java.util.date and ThreadLocalRandom. It say's 'The local variable d1 may not have been initialized'

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.Date;

public class TestDate {

     public static void main(String[] args) {


        Date  d1 = new Date(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(d1.getTime()));


        System.out.println("Today's date is: " + d1.toString());
        System.out.println("Milliseconds: " + d1.getTime());
    }

}
```

When I'm just setting d1 as a variable it says 'Duplicate local variable d1'

I don't get where my mistake is

Comment: Judging by your code, you want the random number to be between 0 and the current time?

Comment: Well, sure: where is the `d1` in `new Date(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(d1.getTime()));` supposed to come from? You're still in the process of declaring it, what is `d1.getTime()` supposed to be?

Comment: You use d1 in the inizialization of d1?

Comment: getTime() should give me the time in milliseconds.

Comment: But you use it in the inizialization of d1 itself. This would bei the same If you would try Something like Integer a =a+1 you cannot use a variable as long as it not clear what the variable is

Comment: You can try it when you substitute d1.getTime() with a given value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Local variable may not have been initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11860337/local-variable-may-not-have-been-initialized)

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `Instant` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: It’s still not clear what your goal is, so hard to help you get there. *getTime() should give me the time in milliseconds.* Which time??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually initialize `d1` before you can invoke any methods on it. Consider the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Date d1 = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    d1 = new Date(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(d1.getTime()));

    System.out.println("Today's date is: " + d1.toString());
    System.out.println("Milliseconds: " + d1.getTime());
}
```

You see that I initialize the variable using `Calendar.getInstance().getTime()` *before* trying to invoke `d1.getTime()` in the constructor.

If it at all helps you understand the situation, you could use two separate variables to achieve the same end, as I did below:

```
Date d1 = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
Date d2 = new Date(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(d1.getTime()));
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and your work, you helped me a lot

Answer (score 1):

### Don’t use Date. Use Instant.

```
    Instant now = Instant.now();
    Instant someTime = Instant.ofEpochMilli(
            ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(now.toEpochMilli()));
    System.out.println(someTime);
```

Example output:

> 2000-09-12T12:14:59.258Z

The code generates a random point in time between the epoch of January 1, 1970 00:00 UTC (inclusive) and now (exclusive).

The `Date` class that you were trying to use is poorly designed and fortunately long outdated. Don’t use it. Use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with. The class to use for a moment in time is `Instant`.

### What went wrong in your code?

```
    Date  d1 = new Date(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(d1.getTime()));
```

In this line you are trying to declare a variable `d1` and assign it an initial value using the value if `d1`. This creates a circular dependency. While defining something in terms of itself *may occasionally* work in human language because humans can think for themselves, it doesn’t work in Java. So you would have needed to pass something else that doesn’t depend on `d1` to `nextLong`.

Exception: You may say that a recursive method is defined in terms of itself. But that’s a different story.

Your compiler said:

> The local variable d1 may not have been initialized

We had wanted a clearer error message. In this case it could safely have said *has not been initialized* (the same message is used in situations where the *may not* is appropriate). It is worth noting that it pointed to the `d1` in `d1.getTime()`: You were trying to use the value of `d1` before it was initialized.

### Tutorial link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Answer (score 1):

You should prefer to use LocalDate instead (or LocalDateTime if you want to use time too). Date and Calendar are quite old and not recommended.

For example, if you want to get it from epoch day, you can use `LocalDate.ofEpochDay` .

Here's a sample to get a random date from one date to another (including both) :

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private fun getRandomDate(startDate: LocalDate, endDate: LocalDate): LocalDate {
    val randomDay = Random.nextLong(startDate.toEpochDay(), endDate.toEpochDay() + 1)
    return LocalDate.ofEpochDay(randomDay)
}
```

Usage:

```
val randomDate = getRandomDate(LocalDate.now().minusYears(100), LocalDate.now().plusYears(100))
Log.d("AppLog", "randomDate:$randomDate")
```

I know it's in Kotlin, but the same should work for Java.

Answer (score 0):

`Date d1 = new Date(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(d1.getTime()));`

You call `d1.getTime()` as `d1` is being initialized.